# Can't connect to MySQL from C# windows application

Tags: c#, mysql

I implement an C# windows application and I always connected to sql server for testing.
Now I would like to connect it to the MySQL on hosting server to link some booking data from my website.
I use the same address and port that shows on the url when I connect to the phpMyAdmin.
And this is my configuration in my application.

```
private string connectionStr = "SERVER=203.78.yyy.xx;PORT=2082;DATABASE=db_name;UID=user;PASSWORD=password;";
```

But I always receive the timeout exception and I don't know what is the problem exactly.
I also tried to connect with phpMyAdmin on my localhost and it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's **MySQL**, not phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @SLaks Do you mean the tags? edited!

Comment: You're probably fighting a firewall.

Comment: @SLaks If it's like what you think. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Tell your host to allow remote connections.

Comment: I don't think you use the right attribute names in your connection string. Try                                                              "Data Source=203.78.yyy.xx;Initial Catalog=db_name; ; User ID= id;Password=pwd"

Comment: @neo Doesn't work. I got another error MySqlException, Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to connect using Server Explorer I had to install an ADO.NET driver [MySQL .NET Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

To connect via code, I was adding a reference to MySql.Data.dll and connection string such as

> "Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"

And I was getting the timeout too, but only when the data was rather big. The problem was with TCP/IP ports and the solution I found is in [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553549), also checkout this [blog](http://ziya.suzen.net/2009/01/mysql-high-volume-connection-issue-when.html)